# ipywidgets not rendering with nbconvert using jupyter/scipy-notebook docker image

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, nbconvert

When I convert a notebook containing an ipywidget, the widget doesn't render, only the label is printed. Is it possible to get nbconvert to render the ipywidget when converting to html or pdf? I don't need interactivity, just a static image.

Here is the notebook defining a slider widget

[image]

And here is the output after running `nbconvert --to pdf widget-test.ipynb`

[image]

I went through the process of saving the notebook widget state according to the [official instructions](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/embedding.html#save-notebook-widget-state) before converting the notebook.

I am using the latest [jupyter/scipy-notebook](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/scipy-notebook) docker image.